# How to change View-elements in child ConstraintLayout from parent ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My parent ConstraintLayout includes a button and a child Constraint Layout.
The child ConstraintLayout includes a textview.

How can I programmatically change the text of the textview with the button? Using below method doesn't work;

```
public void onSubmit(View view) {
   textviewInChildConstraintLayout.setText("Changed text...");
}
```

Comment: What is `textviewInChildConstraintLayout`? Is it a `TextView` or `ConstraintLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to convert the textView to EditText in order to setText

convert by placing (EditText) before the textView object

try this:

> ((EditText)textviewInChildConstraintLayout).setText("Changed text...");